# Replace text in facebook create post field using chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I'm working with chrome extension project like **google input tool**. It replace the english characters to another language while typing. 
It work well with all input,textarea,content editable div and iframes including 
**blogger, gmail, twitter, linkedin**.

When typing facebook create post field, it shows the all words with replaced new characters.
But when post it, last character of the sentence did not replaced (it shows in english) and if i press space then post, it post with last replaced character.

Seems my problem can solve if i press space end of the sentence(it's not practical). So i tried to simulate key press event with space but it not work for this.

I used javascript `'window.getSelection()'` method to select and replace the characters in content editable div.

Why this is happening and is there any way to change or inject characters in to facebook create post field using javascript?